# I am creating multiple "single" select tags dynamically in html using angularjs. Two columns contain two different select tags. I want the second

Tags: angularjs

I have two columns in which I generate select tags dynamically. So if there are four rows, four select tags for each column. I want that the second select tag of column2 should only be selectable when a particular option in the first select tag has been selected.

```
<tbody ng-init="count=0">

                    <tr ng-repeat="a in CustomerCallDetails">
                     <td colspan="1">{{a.first_name}} {{a.last_name}}</td>
                        <td colspan="1">{{a.date}}</td>
                        <td colspan="1">{{a.parent_classification_name}}({{a.parent_brand}})</td>
                        <td colspan="1">&#8377; {{a.customer_revenue | number}}</td>
                        <td colspan="1">{{a.phone}}</td>
                        <td>
                        <select><option ng-click="!disableSelect[count];count=count+1">Called</option><option selected="selected">Not Called</option></select>
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="1">
                         <select ng-disabled="disableSelect[count]"><option>Called</option><option selected="selected">Not Called</option></select>
                        </td>

                    </tr>

                </tbody>
```

This is the code I have tried till now. But it doesnt seem to work. I have a for loop in my controller that defines disabledSelect as true. Where am I going wrong? I am new to angular. Maybe this sounds like a very tiny problem.

Comment: post the code for your controller or the data that loops for ng-repeat.

Comment: Post the JS . And it will be better if you could post the demo UI you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a look at this example to infer idea and adapt it on your existing code.

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <fieldset ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
        <select 
            ng-options="p.id as p.first for p in people"
            ng-model="selectedPerson"></select>
        <select ng-disabled='selectedPerson === 2'
            ng-options="p.id as p.actor for p in actor"
            ng-model="selectedActor"></select>
            selected person id: {{selectedPerson}}
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Controller

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
myapp.controller('FirstCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.people = [
        { id: 1, first: 'John',  actor: 'Silvester' },
        { id: 2, first: 'Rocky',actor: 'Silvester' },
        { id: 3, first: 'John',actor: 'Arnold' },
        { id: 4, first: 'Ben',actor: 'Arnold' }
    ];

      $scope.actor = [
        { id: 1, actor: 'Silvester' },
        { id: 2, actor: 'Silvester' },
        { id: 3, actor: 'Arnold' },
        { id: 4, actor: 'Arnold' }
    ];
});
```

Here the first select dropdown is for the people and the value for the `<option>` is the `id` of the people. So, whenever the people with `id:2` is selected the select dropdown for the Actor is disabled.

For your simplicity and further experiment here is the link to [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xs2dm2qt/1/)

Comment: I voted it up but as I just joined the community it wont show my votes.